# Underline text line with dashes in vim

Tags: vim

Is there a nice quick way to have a text line underlined with dashes (exact same length)? For purpose of rst documents (sub)*sections have to have single character underlings of the same length as previous. So section heading should look like

`In this section main character dies
-----------------------------------`

My current approach is to look at the position of cursor (when I'm at the end of the line) and then: `o{N}I-` where `{N}` is the cursors position. I'd much rather have some nice macro to do it with custom character.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Copy the line with `Y`, paste it with `p`, and replace everything with `-` using `Vr-` (select the line, replace character by `-`).

So:

```
YpVr-
```

*Note*: This assumes you don't have the somewhat common `Y` -> `y$` mapping. If you do, use `yy` instead of `Y`.

---

If you want a (crude) mapping to do this a bit faster, you could use something like:

```
:nnoremap <leader>u YpVr
```

then typing `\u-` (assuming you haven't changed the leader key) would underline a line with `-`.

Comment: Right. Didn't realise that V get whole current line. Makes obvious sense ;-)

Comment: You might want to use a different register in your mapping, to avoid that the default register is replaced by the text of the headline when the mapping is used.

Answer (score 4):

I think you might like the extline plugin: https://github.com/drmikehenry/vim-extline

It was designed for to work with reStructuredText documents, and I've been using it for years (actually for more years than it's been available as a plugin, since I've been using Dr. Mike's configuration for quite some time now).

With it you can start the line by typing the character you want and typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.  Or use one of the other [available shortcuts](https://github.com/drmikehenry/vim-extline/blob/master/doc/extline.txt#L68):

```
The following mappings apply in Visual and Insert modes (but, notably, NOT in
Normal mode):

CTRL-L CTRL-L     Auto-line update
CTRL-L CTRL-H     Horizontal line update
CTRL-L CTRL-U     Change to underlined title
CTRL-L CTRL-O     Change to overlined title
CTRL-L CTRL-I     Change to underlined and overlined title

CTRL-L =          Force Section heading (level 1)
CTRL-L 1
CTRL-L -          Force Subsection heading (level 2)
CTRL-L 2
CTRL-L ^          Force Subsubsection heading (level 3)
CTRL-L 3
CTRL-L "          Force Paragraph heading (level 4)
CTRL-L 4
CTRL-L '          Force level 5 heading (level 5)
CTRL-L 5
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Someone else's answer was more precise to the question, but your input is very valuable. I'll take a look at it!

Comment: No worries!  I figured someone would chime in with a more direct answer, but I think the plugin is definitely worth taking a look at. :-)